# Traversing JavaScript AST (Esprima.Net) to Tree in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, abstract-syntax-tree

I used Esprima.Net (https://github.com/Diullei/Esprima.NET) to get AST (Abstract Syntax Key) from a JavaScript code. It returns a `List<Dynamic>` consisting many child and sub-child nodes. I wonder how best to traverse all these nodes in C# for analysis. Basically I want to get the function name, variable name & function that it is under.

For example, in the following JavaScript code:

```
var y = 45;
function fTest(d)
{
   var key: Argument.Callee;
   var cars = 'Hello';
   for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) 
   { 
     text += cars[i];
   }
}
```

I wish to get the following result at the end:

```
variable: 45
function:parameter:'d'
function:variable:argument.callee
function:variable:'Hello'
funtion:loop:variable:object
```

I'm having a difficulty to traverse the `List<Dynamic>` given by Esprima.Net. Any ideas to process or traverse this list in a Tree or any structure so that I can access them? Thanks.

Comment: I did something with Esprima in the past and I ended up implementing it using NodeJS. Since Esprima is made in JS (ok, there's this .NET port... but I mean the official one), analyzing JS from JS feels a bit more simple. Maybe you can also do the whole work using [Jurassic](https://jurassic.codeplex.com/) and then read the results from .NET.

Comment: After looking around, it seems that Jurassic does not create AST unless modification to its code is made. I ended up using Esprima JS and an external Javascript as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up not using the Esprima.NET but Esprima JS (http://esprima.org/). I added Esprima JS in webpage and create an external javascript file that called Esprima parser to create AST. Once I had the AST, I used estraverse (https://github.com/estools/estraverse) to traverse the AST to get results.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) which is a JavaScript interpreter in .NET, and has an internal port of Esprima (ES5). It returns the same AST as Esprima.

Or you can use this other [Esprima.NET](https://github.com/sebastienros/esprima-dotnet) that is based on ES6 and distributed separately from Jint.